# Spacy is_stop doesn't identify stop words?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

When I use SpaCy to identify stopwords, it doesn't work if I use the `en_core_web_lg` corpus, but it does work when I use `en_core_web_sm`. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

doc = nlp(u'The cat ran over the hill and to my lap')

for word in doc:
    print(f' {word} | {word.is_stop}')
```

Result:

```
 The | False
 cat | False
 ran | False
 over | False
 the | False
 hill | False
 and | False
 to | False
 my | False
 lap | False
```

However, when I change this line to use the `en_core_web_sm`corpus, I get different results:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

 The | False
 cat | False
 ran | False
 over | True
 the | True
 hill | False
 and | True
 to | True
 my | True
 lap | False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is a documented [bug](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1574). The suggested workaround is the following:

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
for word in STOP_WORDS:
    for w in (word, word[0].capitalize(), word.upper()):
        lex = nlp.vocab[w]
        lex.is_stop = True

doc = nlp(u'The cat ran over the hill and to my lap')

for word in doc:
    print('{} | {}'.format(word, word.is_stop))
```

**Output**

```
The | False
cat | False
ran | False
over | True
the | True
hill | False
and | True
to | True
my | True
lap | False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS`, then you can explicitly check if the words are in the set

```
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

doc = nlp(u'The cat ran over the hill and to my lap')

for word in doc:
    # Have to convert Token type to String, otherwise types won't match
    print(f' {word} | {str(word) in STOP_WORDS}')
```

Outputs the following:

```
The | False
 cat | False
 ran | False
 over | True
 the | True
 hill | False
 and | True
 to | True
 my | True
 lap | False
```

Looks like a bug to me. However, this approach also gives you the flexibility of adding words to the `STOP_WORDS` set, if you need to